# How can I ping a range of IP addresses simultaneously

Tags: windows, networking, ip-address, ping, scanning

I have a bunch of machines on an IP address range which I want to ping simultaneously as a quick and dirty way of telling which ones are switched on. What (free) software can I use to do this?

I'm using [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista).

Comment: I tried angry ip scanner and free ip scanner and angry seems faster after increasing it's maximum thread count to the range of IPs I was after.

Comment: there's a slight chance this might trip off some kind of security. It might be a better bet to have the machines set to ping a central server at certain intervals, or check at the router.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The quickest way is to use [Angry IP Scanner](http://www.angryip.org)

[image]

I use it for the same way you want to!

Comment: It is free? I have been using it for years.

Comment: Er.. yes it is?

Comment: That's so good! :D +1

Comment: This sets off some Antivirus signatures for "Potentially Unwanted Program".  I suggest using NirSoft's [PingInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multiple_ping_tool.html) instead.

Comment: @iszi False positive... I still think this is the best program for the job.

Comment: @WilliamHilsum Perhaps AngryIP is the better program, but NirSoft is corporate AV friendly.  Important for when you don't get to control the AV's whitelist.

Comment: @iszi - sort of surprising since so many of their tools do get picked up! That is a good point, however a quick note to people who see this here -  I just tried using it, and, I do like it... for one or two IPs, but, for example at work, I need to quickly scan entire subnets - I can do this with just 3 clicks on angry IP, I couldn't see a way to do that on here.

Comment: @WilliamHilsum Yeah, that is one downfall of PingInfoView I'm hoping Nir will fix some time.  The feature is available in some of his other tools, like FastResolver.  The only NirSoft tools I've had problems with in regards to AV are those which are related to password cracking/recovery.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is Open Source and the [source code](https://github.com/angryip/ipscan) is hosted on Github

Answer (score 49):

[Nmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap) is available for Windows:

```
# nmap -sP 10.0.10.1-100
```

Comment: nmap is absolutely a great piece of software

Comment: on some newer versions of nmap, this is `-sn` to run a "no port scan", just looking for hosts.

Answer (score 15):

I've used this command

```
for %%i in 200 to 254 do ping 10.1.1.%%i
```

in a batch file for a similar reason

Comment: are you sure it does a simultaneous ping? or is it one machine after another!

Comment: agreed, not simultaneous

Comment: You're right it's sequential rather than simultaneous

Comment: This gives me an error "200 was unexpected at this time". Are you sure this is the right syntax?

Answer (score 12):

### [Free IP Scanner 1.6](http://www.eusing.com/ipscan/free_ip_scanner.htm)

Here is the range of IP addresses as you can notice in:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Instead of manually pinging all IP addresses on your LAN you can do the following:

Open a Command Prompt and type:

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO ping -n 1 192.168.0.%i | FIND /i "Reply">>C:\ipaddresses.txt
```

`-n 1` means that only 1 ping packet will be sent to each computer.

Change `192.168.0` to match you own network ID.

This will ping all IP addresses on the 192.168.0.0 network segment and create a text file called `ipaddresses.txt` in C:\, where it will list only the IP addresses that gave a reply.

You can also add `-a` to the ping command to resolve all the responding IP addresses to hostnames, but doing so will cause the script to take a considerable time to finish:

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO ping -a -n 1 192.168.0.%i | FIND /i "Reply">>C:\ipaddresses.txt
```

Comment: This still pings them one at a time though doesn't it? Angry IP scanner pings all IP's in the subnet at once by launching multiple threads so it takes very little time to complete a whole scan.

Comment: Works very well in situations where no external program can be installed on the machine, and/or only a text console is available. The only caveat for international users is that the "Reply" string must be changed to whatever the local version of ping is using. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

try [fping](http://fping.sf.net)

Comment: It's available on brew for OSX too (incase anyone surfed from Google and missed Windows in the title.)

Answer (score 4):

You could just write a [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) script that loops through an IP address range and pings them. An example that pings addresses in the range 10.1.1.1 to 10.1.1.255 (inclusive):

```
for i in {100..255}
do
    ping 10.1.1.$i
done
```

Comment: I think that "500" wants to be 255 or less?

Comment: And I think `ping 10.1.1.i` probably wants to be `ping 10.1.1.$i`.

Comment: also not simultaneous

Comment: I belive you will need to pass the "-c" flag. Something like "ping -c1  192.168.1.1". otherwise, you will be stuck fora while.

Answer (score 3):

Save the below script on the server with an extension of `.bat` or `.cmd` and call the file from the command prompt. It should prompt you to enter the IP address range.

Please enter only three octets of the IP address.

---

```
@echo off

SET count=0
SET /p subnet=Please enter IP address range (for example, 192.168.0)

:start
SET /a count=%count%+1

cls
ECHO. & ECHO Trying %subnet%.%count% & ECHO.

ping -n 1 -w 1000 %subnet%.%count% >nul  
IF %errorlevel%==0 echo %subnet%.%count% UP >> c:\pingnet.log  
IF %errorlevel%==1 echo %subnet%.%count% DOWN >> c:\pingnet.log

IF %count%==254 goto :eof

GOTO start
```

---

Once the command has run, it will create a text file name `pingnet.log` in the root of C drive. That file should give you a list of used and down (free) IP addresses.

For example:

```
10.2.214.1 UP   
10.2.214.2 UP   
10.2.214.3 UP   
10.2.214.4 DOWN
```

It is pretty simple to run, and it should save you loads of time.

Comment: This is actually pretty slow compared to angry IP scanner as it does them one at a time. Unless most of the IP range is used, you'd have to wait minutes for this approach to give you an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Angry IP Scanner is great, but I prefer CLI tools. See if you can get this powershell script running in Vista. https://github.com/webstersprodigy/PowerSploit/blob/Portscan/Recon/Invoke-Portscan.ps1

I also suggest getting access to a Linux CLI by using a linux live cd/usb, dual boot, or a vm in VirtualBox. (Install VirtualBox, add a new vm, install Debian.) A linux CLI is invaluable.

From a linux CLI, run the following:

## PING Based Scan

```
for ip in 172.10.1.{1..254}; do ping -c 1 -w 1 $ip > /dev/null && echo $ip "$(nslookup $ip | grep 'name = ' | awk -F ' = ' '{print $2}')"; done
```

Adjust for your network range (the '172.10.1' part,) and you're off. This will provide a list of all hosts on the network that respond to ICMP echo (ping) requests, and resolve them against your DNS server.

Note: This is not the most reliable way to test for live hosts as they may have ICMP blocked.

## nmap Based Scan

nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24

Note: Nmap is more reliable as it is a port scanner and bases its results on the activity on more than just ICMP responses. It's heavily used by pentesters and is worth learning.