# how to access my Billion 7800VDOX router web UI after having configured it in bridge mode (modem)?

Tags: networking, user-interface, bridge-router, billion

Unfortunately the ip address I usually use doeesn't work.

No reference in the manual or whatever.

The router is doing its job as a modem (connected to a router).

Comment: Try 192.168.100.1 as per one of the RFC standards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the IP address of my client bridge router?](http://superuser.com/questions/92022/how-can-i-find-the-ip-address-of-my-client-bridge-router)

Comment: what is a "client bridge router"? no ipconfig here either (linux).. that answer is so confusing, sorry!