# Windows command to display all IP addresses

Tags: windows, networking, ip

I know there is a single line of a command and its arguments that can help display all computer IP addresses (those that are being used) on a LAN, and my computer is also a client, as one of those displayed, but I forgot. What is it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in such a generic way.

Comment: You would have to ping-scan the local subnet and then use the arp -a command listed below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I ping a range of IP addresses simultaneously](http://superuser.com/questions/45687/how-can-i-ping-a-range-of-ip-addresses-simultaneously)

Comment: It better to check all the IP address using 'Angry IP address'.

Answer (score 39):

You could do the `arp -a` command to show all *ARP* entries in the table about computers on your network.

[Source](http://www.computerhope.com/arphlp.htm)

Comment: It shows every system your computer is aware of/talked to - however, it may not be complete - I ran a quick experiment with arp -a and it didn't show one or two of my systems till I pinged it.

Comment: Ya, like the link I posted said, it won't show everything unless it has them stored in the tables so so machines won't be shown but it does do a pretty good list.

Comment: Welcone to Stack Exchange, Gigabit Pony! When a link makes up most of your answer, you should always quote the important parts in case it dies later. See also the [howto on writing good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This use to work, but I've noticed lately, it only shows static IPs like DNS, Mail, local, instead of external IPs that applications are talking too.   When I use arp -a these days it shows 2 dynamic IPs and they are both on my network and the other I'm not even goint to attempt to look them up as they are all under the same A-Class..  224.0.0.2..

Answer (score 36):

Not everything with an IP address is a computer - I found none of these suggestions returned all active IP addresses - in fact most returned very few.  My home network has a combination of wired and wireless devices and two routers, mobile phones, TV, PVR, Apple AirPort and probably a few things I have forgotten.  I used the following to scan all addresses on the 192.168.1.xxx subnet:

```
for /L %i in (0,1,255) do ping -n 1 -w 250 192.168.1.%i>>ipaddress.txt
```

The resulting file ipaddress.txt contains the ping results for all addresses and I looked for those with "`Received = 1`" - currently 16 addresses returned a result - I only have 4 computers in the house - and they were not all on.

Comment: A suggested edit (rolled back) `for /L %i in (0,1,255) do ping -n 1 192.168.1.%i -4 | findstr -m "bytes=32" >> ipaddress.txt` has merit, but is not fundamental to the answer, not consistent with the rest of the answer which used `Received = 1` rather than `bytes=32`, and is not necessarily the way I'd have done it.  I am adding this comment should anyone find the suggestion useful.

Comment: `for /L %i in (1,1,254)` might be more appropriate, since `xxxxxx.0` is the address of the whole network and `xxxxxx.255` is the broadcast address.

Comment: I consider the rejected edit, which pipes to `findstr`, an improvement as well. Though isn’t that `-m` option to `findstr` wrong? I think you could use no option at all, or `-l`. And perhaps `-i` because the string `bytes=32` may be localized and thus capitalized.

Comment: @caw Fine, but it was not _my_ answer. The suggester should simply have posted its own answer. However, it simply adds post-processing to filter the result, and that could be done in any number of ways and is not essential to the general method.  What anyone does with the result is up to them.

Comment: The thing is that the question asked for a way to retrieve certain information. And the improvement suggested in that edit gets you to that information *faster*, cutting down on the *noise*. This is not some arbitrary post-processing according to one’s taste. But I agree, editing your answer was the wrong form. Since it’s not a *new* solution but just an improvement, a separate answer is not warranted, perhaps. But a comment is perfect – which is what you added. Thanks!

Comment: @Clifford the goal is to make this answer the best state it can be, not represent you the best

Comment: @ThatRealtorProgrammerGuy my original response stands.  It was not "better" in any event as I recall this long after the event. The point is it has my name to it, and my rep would be affected by any voting and I was not prepared to be considered responsible for that content.  Had I no choice but to accept it, I would simply delete the content.

Answer (score 12):

There is the `net view /all` command which will list all of the computer names that are connected to the same LAN.

From that you can retrieve the individual IP addresses using the `nslookup <computer name>` command or write a batch script to do it for you.

Here is an example batch I threw together to illustrate.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "xNext="
set "xComputer="
for /f %%A in ('net view /all') do (
    set "xComputer=%%~A"
    if "!xComputer:~0,2!"=="\\" for /f "tokens=2,* delims=. " %%X in ('nslookup %%A') do (
        if "!xNext!"=="1" (
            echo.!xComputer! = %%X.%%Y
            set "xNext=0"
        )
        if "!xComputer:~2!"=="%%~X" set "xNext=1"
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

Answer (score 9):

Aside from `arp -a`, `net view /all`, or writing a batch script there is no native/built-in command line to do this (at least not that I know of).

If you're willing to use a non-native command, I would suggest using [Nmap](https://nmap.org/). You can run `nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24` (replacing the subnet with the appropriate one for your LAN) to achieve what you're looking for, more reliably so than `net view /all` or `arp -a` in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

As indicated by someone else, you can use `arp -a` however make sure that you ping a broadcast address first so that ARP reports all the devices. For example, `ping 192.168.0.255`

you get a list of all devices connected to the network by their IP and MAC addresses. you can look up the MAC addresses on a website like https://aruljohn.com/mac.pl to find out who the vendor of the NIC is. This should help you narrow down what most of the devices are. i.e. computers, printers, TV, cell phone, etc..

Comment: that was the trick... Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I made this PowerShell script for myself:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 255; $i++) {
    Test-Connection "192.168.173.$i" -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

the result is very easy to read:

```
Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
SHUREEK-PC    192.168.173.1   192.168.173.1                                             32       0        
SHUREEK-PC    192.168.173.76                                                            32       388      
SHUREEK-PC    192.168.173.78                                                            32       66       
SHUREEK-PC    192.168.173.110 192.168.173.110  fe80::6160:1756:c397:5d6e%3              32       0        
SHUREEK-PC    192.168.173.188 192.168.173.188                                           32       79       
SHUREEK-PC    192.168.173.191 192.168.173.191                                           32       0
```

Comment: One liner in CMD prompt:  `powershell 'for ($i = 1; $i -lt 255; $i++) {Test-Connection "192.168.173.$i" -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}'`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to scan your local network and get a list, then google, download, and run "advanced IP scanner". Its free.

Answer (score 0):

This is my quick solution. It tells  you what type of device is connected at each ip address:

```
netstat -r
```

Comment: No it doesn't; It displays the routing table

Answer (score 0):

> display all computer IP addresses (those that are being used)

I think you might mean `netstat -a` this gives you an active list. If you want to know the program using the ip address then use `netstat -b` (open as administrator).

Comment: Technically speaking, `netstat -a` dumps a list of current network connections. The left IP address column contains the local interface.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer... I dont think theres a one line Windows OS command to accommodate easily. The easiest way is to see this list in your router software. Simply enter the Default Gateway IP into your browser and log on to your router. It is usually directly on the 1st page that comes up. BTW - if you don't know your Gateway IP - ipconfig will provide it.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo ls %USERDNSDOMAIN%|nslookup
```

Comment: Welcome to SU. Can you please elaborate on what the command do?

Answer (score -1):

`ipconfig /all` (use forward slash, not backwards)

Comment: ipconfig lists the interfaces of the PC itself and not the IP addresses used on the LAN.

Answer (score -1):

very very simple.
use CMD type IPConfig/all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, this displays the IP address(es) of the local computer. It does not list the addresses of computers on the LAN.