# View computers connected to the network and their IP address with one command

Tags: windows, networking, cmd.exe

I would like to do the equal of

```
net view /all
```

followed by

```
nslookup COMPUTERNAME
```

in a oneliner rendering something like

```
\\COMPUTERNAME1      192.168.1.1
\\COMPUTERNAME2      192.168.1.2
```

Can I? Or do I really need to script it like it's done [here](https://superuser.com/a/522684/234237)?

Comment: What wrong with using the script? It does exactly what you want, and according to the link is the only way of doing it.

Comment: Well the script isn't available on any random computer I might want to check ip adressess on...